# SelectOutput5 is not triggering when condition is true

Tags: anylogic

I want to use SelectOutput5 block in order to differentiate same agents according to machines which they have been assigned. As you can see the images, one of the example of  my SelectOutput5 block's condition is;

```
agent.st2Tezgah == "M117";
```

However even though st2Tezgah parameter has M117 value in it, it does not trigger and it goes false section.

I check the parameter with `traceln(agent.st2Tezgah)` as you can see the image, the value is true.

Why SelectOutput5 does not trigger properly?

[Flowchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cd0pf.png)

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHlrh.png)

[Traceln](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kadKW.png)

[st2Tezgah parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UISto.png)

[DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asQDt.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbI1t.png)

Comment: Can you add the `st2Tezgah` variable/parameter's screenshot? What is the type of it?

Comment: I added parameter's screenshot.

Comment: Thanks, it is a parameter. Change it to a variable type and see if the error persists. Yaşar

Comment: I have just tested. But it does not work.

Comment: Something is not correct. Check if you correctly assign the `st2Tezgah`. Maybe when setting `agent.st2Tezgah` you set it to `"M117 "` (with unintentional blank spaces).

Comment: I double checked again. There is no blank spaces in my DB. Also the problem is not only on "M117", other conditions are not triggering too. I added two images; DB view and model result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. Always compare strings using `.equals("myString")`, not `==`.
2. Make sure you do not set the `st2Tezgah` variable "just before" the SelectOutput5. Try having a delay (with 0 duration) before it and see if it works. If so, you need to learn about the difference of "on exit" and "on at exit" (subtle but important here)

Comment: My problem solved when using .equals("M117") . Thank you so much Benjamin!